Create react-hook-form useController reusable field component with proper typing
I try to create a reusable form field component with react-hook-form's useController. Here is how this component looks (<FieldText /> is a presentation logic component):
import { FieldValues, useController, UseControllerProps } from 'react-hook-form';
import FieldText from '@/components/fields/FieldText';

type ControlledFieldTextProps<T extends FieldValues> = UseControllerProps<T> & {
    fieldId?: string;
    className?: string;
    scope?: string | string[];
};

function ControlledFieldText<T extends FieldValues>({
    name,
    control,
    fieldId = '',
    className = '',
    defaultValue,
    scope = [],
}: ControlledFieldTextProps<T>) {
    const {
        field: { value, onBlur, onChange },
        fieldState: { error },
    } = useController({ name, control, defaultValue });

    return (
        <FieldText
            id={fieldId || name}
            value={value}
            className={className}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onValueChange={onChange}
            error={error?.message}
            scope={scope}
        />
    );
}

export default ControlledFieldText;

It works, but when I try to provide defaultValue I am able to provide any type of value possible in current form. E.g. I have string, number and Date inputs in current form, value of all those types may be passed as defaultValue to my component. I want to narrow it down only to string.
Also I want to provide "" as default value, but cannot do it because value of type PathValue<T, Path<T>> is expected there.

Hint: Take a look at the type definition for UseControllerProps. In general, I'm curious why people try to create these generic components in their own codebases. It's often because to specify their form fields as configuration (like an array or something) instead of just writing out the declarative code for each field and using react-hook-form's generic components (which they've already created with solid type definitions for you to just use - you're just recreating them). Declaring form fields as arrays feels fancier/more "pro programmer", but writing the declarative code is way simpler.

@AdamJenkins I agree, I work on some other project with form generator, and I cannot say I am happy about the DX, there were dozens of times I thought it would be much better to have it all declarative though more cluttered.

@AdamJenkins in this particular case things just got to copy-pasty, I have to wrap all my fields with Controller and pass properties like onBlur, onChange etc. So I decided why not do a controlled version of each field and isolate and reuse at least half of logics

DRY is vastly overrated. Program for ease of change. More importantly, the devs that come along after you won't have to understand how your code works (or be tempted to change it, probably in a bad way) they can just read react-hook-form docs and use your stuff as an example. Your question is still valid and I know I haven't answered it, I've just been burned too many times by trying to create the abstraction that's actually already been created and getting myself caught because I didn't create code that was easy to change. You're building an app, not a library.

All that above is opinion, thanks for the chat, I'll see if I can reproduce your problem with a stackblitz and offer a real solution now

@AdamJenkins My main goal is to remove at least some part of this clutter
<Controller   name="email"   defaultValue=""   control={control}   render={({ field: { onBlur, onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (     <FieldText       id="email"       value={value}       error={error?.message}       onBlur={onBlur}       onValueChange={onChange}       scope={scope.email}      />    )} />
It just feels wrong to copy/paste all this when you have few forms with 10 fields. But I agree with above, it's easy to read and you just feel safe in case you need to cherry-tweak smth

I think if you duplicate the entire UseControllerProps type definition it'll work for you (provided you specify the types of TFieldValues and TFieldName whenever you call your component):
import {
  FieldPath,
  FieldValues,
  useController,
  UseControllerProps,
} from 'react-hook-form';

type ControlledFieldTextProps<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>
> = UseControllerProps<TFieldValues, TName> & {
  fieldId?: string;
  className?: string;
  scope?: string | string[];
};

export function ControlledFieldText<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues = FieldValues,
  TName extends FieldPath<TFieldValues> = FieldPath<TFieldValues>
>({
  name,
  control,
  fieldId = '',
  className = '',
  defaultValue,
  scope = [],
}: ControlledFieldTextProps<TFieldValues, TName>) {
  const {
    field: { value, onBlur, onChange },
    fieldState: { error },
  } = useController({ name, control, defaultValue });

  return ....
}


As I illustrated in my comment, this is likely to be an ill-advised/unnecessary abstraction. It'll save a handful of lines of code when you're building forms, but this pattern is not in the react-hook-form docs - people won't just be able to refer to docs when they use it (if you're on a team) - and I can guarantee that somebody will eventually come along and add something to this abstraction for a specific use case that has no business being there.
The above code should work just fine for your use case, personally would recommend to just stick to the docs.
Also, did you know if you use a FormProvider then you don't need to prop-drill control?

control object provided by invoking useForm. Optional when using FormProvider.


Yes, it worked! Thanks! I will check on FormProvider as well, but in my case 1-level drilling is OK I guess

I eventually changed my opinion and will give FormProvider a try, looks handy

BTW when utilising control through FormProvider I lose the defaultValue typing again

@markoffden yeah, that’s because control comes with the typings that UseControllerProps can infer it from. Without a control you have to be explicit about what the values are at the callsite: <ControlledTextField<MyFormValues> {…props} />
